# Armature changes pose for no reason after exporting

Tags: export, pose-mode, gltf, collada

Before I export, I clear the transforms of all the bones in pose mode. I go back to object mode and export the armature and mesh, and the second it's done exporting the armature just magically poses itself to some animation.

Edit: closer inspection shows that it sets the pose to the last frame of the last action in the action list.

I can just go back to pose mode and clear the transforms again, but it's really annoying that it keeps changing the pose for no reason.

This has happened in every version of Blender I've used since 2015. Note that I only work with .dae and .gltf files. Both exporters have this problem.

How can I make it so the pose isn't changed after exporting?

Comment: It's just posing back to the keyframes of the active action.  If you really want, you can reset loc/rot/scale + keyframe your bones, possibly in a new action.

Comment: I have the T-pose as an action. I close any actions open on any objects before exporting and set the frame to zero. So there is no active action and if there was it would be going to frame zero of the T-pose anyway. But it doesn't, it actually poses a blend of two different actions. Edit: actually it's the last action in the (alphabetical) list. It just so happens in this case that my last action is lower body only and the second-last is upper body only.